# a2ensite through shell script

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, bash, virtualhost

I created a small script to add websites on my server and it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName $1
    ServerAlias www.$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/$1/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-$1.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-$1.log combined
</VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1.conf

mkdir /var/www/$1
mkdir /var/www/$1/public_html/

a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1.conf
```

This is working fine.

I can run this script as `./newsite example.com` and I get my file `example.com.conf` under `sites-available` and everything. But when I run `a2ensite`, I've got the following error:

```
ERROR: Site /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com does not exist!
```

It's weird because even though I create a file called `example.com.conf` before I still get this error.

Any ideas? Is this a bug?

PS: Just sudoers are allow to run this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because to `a2ensite` you pass the the full path to your site config. `a2ensite` expects only a site name to be passed:

```
a2ensite example.com
```